# What's the difference between 'state' and 'status' in function name?

Tags: javascript

readyState
statusText
onreadystatechange
window.status

What's the difference between 'state' and 'status' in English ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much.  I would tend to say state refers to more detailed information, but that's subjective.

For these:

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest?PHPSESSID=2ef1794a9912f1aa92ed632563d33624).readyState - one of 5 possible states for a request

XMLHttpRequest.statusText - The text equivalent of the HTTP response status (e.g. "200 OK")

XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange - function to call when readyState changes

[window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status) - status bar text (typically bottom left of window)

Answer (score 2):

They are quite similar, as they both signify the current properties of something. There is however a bit of a difference in how they are used:

A state is usually a single propery with some specific possible values. The `readyState` for example will cycle through some specific predefined values when a page loads.

The status is usually a collection of properties, or a description of them. The `window.status` property for example is just the text that is displayed in the status bar, and that can descibe any aspect of the content.

Answer (score 1):

In computing there is not much difference between the two, and they can be used interchangeably.

See [status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status) and [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State#Applied_sciences_and_mathematics) on wikipedia (the computing sections) - not much of a difference, and the `status` article even points to `state` articles.

Answer (score 1):

`status` in `window.status` points to the status bar of the browser. In pure English though, i don't see much difference between `state` and `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a humble tought: It could help thinking to readyState in a finite state machine fashion. I mean, when a page loads, It goes from a state to another (and not from a status to another status). Maybe this explain why they have decided to call It state.